# Foreach Query Products

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to have a list of products that have id categories as a foreign key, but I don't want to have a query for each product, is there a smarter way to do it? The current code works but I don't think I'm doing it correctly, follow the code:

````
        if($products){
            $categories = [];
            foreach($products as $product){
                $categories[] = $product->categories()->first();
            }
            return view('products',[
                'products' => $products,
                'categories' => $categories
            ]);
        }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it like this
`$categories[] = $product->categories()->first();`

`$product->categories()` does a new instance of the query builder`.

If you want to access the relation with 1 query you need to refer ot it as a method

`$product->categories` this way you will get a collection of all categories.

If you want all categories for a specific product do it like this;

`$product = Product::find(1);` -> this is just example for getting a product with ID 1.

Then you need all categories of this product.

`$product->categories` -> Categories is your relationship in the Product model, we are reffering to it as a `METHOD` not as a `FUNCTION`.

```
            return view('products',[
                'product' => $product,
                'categories' => $product->categories
            ]);
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks bro, i love you

Comment: No problem. If you need more explanation, just tell me :P

Comment: Victor Gabriel, if this answer really helpful, then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eager loading to load the categories of each products without looping through each one :

1. Load all categories of a certain `$products`

```
     if($products){
            $products->with('categories')->get();

            return view('products',$products);
        }
```

2. Load categories of a certain `$products` with extra constraints:

```
     if($products){
            $products->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('...');
            }])->get();;

            return view('products',$products);
        }
```